LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119E) :Differing number of properties in duplicated types (CDeviceSimMsg) : (0x020000003)
When I build my code, I encounter the above LNK Error (build with VS2019)
Is there a way to fix the error?
DeviceSimMsg.cpp
#include "DeviceSimMsg.h"
CDeviceSimMsg::CDeviceSimMsg(void)
{
}

DeviceSimMsg.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;
public ref class CDeviceSimMsg : public Object 
{
    public:
    CDeviceSimMsg(void);

    property unsigned short MsgType
    {
    unsigned short get() {
        return musMsgType;
    }

    void set(unsigned short usValue){
        musMsgType = usValue;
    }
    }

        property int MsgID
        {
            int get() {
        return musMsgID;
    }
    void set(int usValue){
        musMsgID = usValue;
    }
    }

property int EventState
{
    int get() {
        return mucEventState;
    }
    void set(int ucValue){
        mucEventState = ucValue;
    }
}

private:
unsigned short  musMsgType; //1 - events, 2 - data
unsigned short  musMsgID; //Event or Txn ID
unsigned char   mucEventState;
};

To fix the issue so as the compilation is successful.
